# How to convert python nested dict to non-nested dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

How to convert below src dict (nested dict)

```
{
    'a':{'b':1, 'c':{'d':2}},
    'b':3,
    'c':{'d':4, 'a':5}
}
```

to dst dict (not nested) below?

```
{
    'a.b':1,
    'a.c.d':2,
    'b':3,
    'c.d':4,
    'c.a':5
}
```

The src dict is nested dict. And the dst dict is not nested dict.

Any easy method to do this convention?

Comment: A simple recursive version could be enough, but not efficient for big levels of nesting. What did you try already? It is always better to have a starting point in order to help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is python package for flatten dictionary. You can use this

https://pypi.org/project/flatten-dict/

Implementation:

```
from flatten_dict import flatten

nested = {'a': {'b': 1, 'c': {'d': 2}},
          'b': 3,
          'c': {'d': 4, 'a': 5}}

flat = flatten(nested, reducer=lambda k1, k2: k2 if k1 is None else k1 + '.' + k2)
print(flat)
# {'a.b': 1, 'a.c.d': 2, 'b': 3, 'c.d': 4, 'c.a': 5}
```

Comment: flatten_dict not work if list contained in the dict, such as {'b': [{'c':{'d':[1,2,3]}}]}

Comment: What output you are expecting in this case?
{'b.c.d': [1,2,3]} ??

Comment: yes.  {'b': [{'c':{'d':[1,2,3]}}, 'e':[{'f':3}, {'g':6}]]}  to {'b.c.d':[1,2,3], 'b.e.f':3, 'b.e.g':6}

Comment: should not be it something like this..
{'b': [{'c':{'d':[1,2,3]}}, 'e':[{'f':3}, {'g':6}]]} . ---> .   

{'b_0.c.d':[1,2,3], ''b_1.e_0.f":3, b_1.e_1.g:6}

Because list may contain duplicate dictionaries..  indexing also needed in this case?

Comment: Flatten_dict does not flat values if values are list.

Comment: nested = {'b': [{'c':{'d':[1,2,3]}}], 'e' : [{'f':3}, {'g':6}]}

from flatten_json import flatten


print flatten(nested, ".")

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways. Here is one way to do it.

```
    nested_dict = {
        'a': {
            'b': 1,
            'c': {
                'd': 2
            }
        },
        'b': 3,
        'c': {
            'd': 4,
            'a': 5
        },
    }

    flatten_dict = {}

    def flatten_the_nested(nested_dict, parent_key=''):
        for key, value in nested_dict.items():
            new_key = parent_key + '.' + key if parent_key is not '' else key
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                flatten_the_nested(value, new_key)
            else:
                flatten_dict[new_key] = value

        return flatten_dict


     print(flatten_the_nested(nested_dict, ''))
```

You will get the following result.

```
    {'c.d': 4, 'c.a': 5, 'b': 3, 'a.b': 1, 'a.c.d': 2}
```

Or if you want to use some library then you can use https://pypi.org/project/flatten-dict/

Answer (score 0):

Well, its not complicated. In just a few minutes I got the following:

```
def flatten(dic, prefix = ""):
    if prefix is not "":
        prefix = prefix + "."

    result = {}

    for k, v in dic.iteritems():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            for k1, v1 in flatten(v, prefix + k).iteritems():
                result[k1] = v1
        else:
            result[prefix + k] = v

    return result
```

I have not thoroughly tested this algorithm, though.